# What's the penalty for dropping a Google Cloud commitment?

Tags: gcp

Google Cloud is offering me discounts if I commit to a service for three years. I'm having a hard time trying to find out what's the penalty should I leave early.

The discount is tempting, but I'm updating my infrastructure all the time. What if I find a cheaper provider or if I decide to change my infra and suddenly I don't need a service any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No penalties will be incurred in terms of money. If you choose not to use it, you can block the attached card for payments. The only consequence will be the suspension of your account.